# NodeMCU HTTP server stops responding

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I'm trying to make a simple HTTP server with NodeMCU. I start up nodeMCU then connect it to the wifi and then run the program below. I can connect to the server from my browser. If I keep on reloading the page it would work forever, but when I stop sending requests for a minute or two, the server will somehow stop functioning. Which means, when I reload page nodeMCU does not receive any data (and cannot return any data back).

```
a=0

function receive(conn,payload) 
    a=a+1
    print(payload) 

    local content="<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link rel='shortcut icon' href='/'></head><body><h1>Hello!</h1><p>Since the start of the server " .. a .. " connections were made</p></body></html>"
    local contentLength=string.len(content)

    conn:send("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length:" .. contentLength .. "\r\n\r\n" .. content)
    conn:close()
end

function connection(conn) 
    conn:on("receive",receive)
end

srv=net.createServer(net.TCP,1) 
srv:listen(8080,connection)
```

Some things I did:

- I have stopped the browser from requesting favicon by adding the link to nothing.
- I set the timeout for inactive client to 1 to prevent the browser from loading for a long time (the browser keeps on loading until timeout).
- I updated my code to send some HTTP headers.
- I tried closing and opening the server after each connection (no good because if you keep on doing connections it will never stop working even without this fix).
- I added `conn:close()` as suggested by an answer here on StackOverflow.

I'm running precompiled firmware 0.9.6-dev_20150704 integer.

###### Edit: A solution burried in the comments below

The problem was some sort of incompatiblity between my AP and NodeMCU. To keep NodeMCU responding, I had to keep pinging it from my computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't use those old 0.9.x binaries. They're no longer supported and contain lots of bugs. Build a custom firmware from the `dev` (1.5.1) or `master` (1.4) branch: http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev/en/build/.

With version >1.0 of the SDK (this is what you get if you build from current branches) `conn:send` is fully asynchronous i.e. you can't call it multiple consecutive times. Also, you must not call `conn:close()` right after `conn:send()` as the socket would possibly get closed before `send()` is finished. Instead you can listen to the `sent` event and close the socket in its callback. Your code works fine on an up-to-date firmware if you consider this.

A more elegant way of asynchronous sending is documented in the [NodeMCU API docs for `socket:send()`](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev/en/modules/net/#example_6). However, that method uses more heap and is not necessary for simple cases with little data like yours.

So, here's the full example with `on("sent")`. Note that I changed the favicon to an external resource. If you use "/" the browser still issues an extra request against your ESP8266.

```
a = 0

function receive(conn, payload)
    print(payload) 
    a = a + 1

    local content="<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link rel='icon' type='image/png' href='http://nodemcu.com/favicon.png' /></head><body><h1>Hello!</h1><p>Since the start of the server " .. a .. " connections were made</p></body></html>"
    local contentLength=string.len(content)

    conn:on("sent", function(sck) sck:close() end)
    conn:send("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\nContent-Length:" .. contentLength .. "\r\n\r\n" .. content)
end

function connection(conn) 
    conn:on("receive", receive)
end

srv=net.createServer(net.TCP, 1) 
srv:listen(8080, connection)
```

Comment: Although I have not tried it yet, your answer covers my problem perfectly and the old firmware probably is the issue.

Comment: Okay I'm now running a new firmware and I just found out that my problem with the server stopping responding is caused probably by my WiFi AP... I had some problems with my tablet periodically disconnecting. Now I tried few times to disconnect from WiFi and connect again when the server stopped responding and the server is running again after that.

Comment: That was actually my first guess...until I saw you're running NodeMCU 0.9.6.

Comment: I fixed my tablet issues by connecting with static IP but for nodeMCU it didn't fix anything so what I did is that I use nodeMCU as AP which works just fine (of course the internet is now unaccessible)

Comment: `wifi.sta.config` uses `auto=1`, right? http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev/en/modules/wifi/#wifistaconfig

Comment: yes that's true... which would mean that I don't need to use wifi.sta.connect() in my connect to AP program

Comment: I just found a way how to keep NodeMCU connected to the AP. It is not the best, but it stays connected if I connect to the AP and then I start pinging NodeMCU form another device.